# CSS Media Print Not Working with React MUI Components After first page break

Tags: css, reactjs, printing, media-queries, tsx

I'm trying to style a react page to be printable using the browser print function using css media queries. However, I'm having issues with using `break-inside: avoid-page` in the media print section. Even though it is supported by google chrome, it seems to only be working the first time it is mentioned. The rest of the time it is ignored.

I have the following React tsx page that is used to render information about a usmler's CV:

```html
        <Stack direction={'column'}>
            <StyledPaper className="paper">
                <Header
                    name={`${cv.common.firstName} ${cv.common.lastName}`}
                    occupation={cv.common.occupation ?? ''}
                />
                <Box style={{ orphans: 1 }} 
                                      display={'flex'} 
                                      flexDirection={'row'} gap={4} mb={4}>
                    <Stack flex={5} gap={4}>
                        <Common />
                        <Languages />
                        <Hobbies />
                    </Stack>
                    <Box flex={10}>
                        <Profile />
                        <Tech />
                    </Box>
                </Box>
                <Education />
                <Certifications />
                <Experience />
            </StyledPaper>
            <Footer />
        </Stack>
```

The page looks like this:
[image]
the footer is not displayed as it is at the bottom of the page.

Now when I use the browser print function, it looks like this:
[image]
[image]

The text from the tech experience and work experience is overflowing over the footer and into the next page. The footer is positioned absolute so it renders on every page using the following media query:

```css
    @media print {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

I tried to use break-inside: avoid-page; as recommended by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside to avoid breaking these divs into multiple pages and it works, but only for the first component.
For the tech component I did:

```css
@media print {
    #tech {
        display: block;
        break-inside: avoid-page;
    }
}
```

And the result:
[image]
Which is exactly what I wanted. However, it doesn't work with the next overflowing element which is the certifications component, where I added following media query:

```css
@media print {
    body {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
    #tech {
        display: block;
        break-inside: avoid-page;
    }
    #certifications {
        display: block;
        break-inside: avoid-page;
    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

All I want is for the elements not to collide with the footer and break before that. I didnt find any CSS to help with that so I'm trying the break-inside: avoid in the media print as a last resort.

I've researched the issue and haven't found any similar article online. Could someone provide more insight? Much appreciated!